# Where are exception logs for VersionOne located?

Tags: logging

Where can I find exception logs for my VersionOne instance?

Answer (score 1):

Look in `%PROGRAMDATA%\VersionOne\Exceptions` for a newer installation.

Also check `http://localhost/V1InstanceName/elmah.axd` for detailed logging.

To enable that URL from machines other than localhost, you must edit Web.config to add `<configuration><elmah><security allowRemoteAccess="0"/>` tags